# How to reinstall Gboard after an accidental uninstall?

Tags: google-play-store, gboard

I accidentally uninstalled Gboard from my tablet. Now, since I can no longer type words, I cannot locate Gboard on the Play Store in order to install it again. Do you know of any work around?

Comment: You can do it using ADB, provide you device details, so I can help you with the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if you've tried this already, but from a browser on a different machine (laptop, desktop, another tablet or phone) you can go to the Play Store (http://play.google.com/store) and log in to the Google account you use on the tablet, and then find the app(s) you'd like to install. You should be able to install the app(s) to your device from there. At least, I've done this for an Android phone.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that from another desktop and it says that Gboard is installed but why it says that when I am not able to locate and use it? I guess I am not understanding how to transfer an install to the tablet.

Comment: I located the device under "Device Manager" but how to install the app I want then?

Comment: @Allan what Meghan suggests is to follow [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) (goes directly to GBoard at the Playstore) and, being logged in with your account, hit the "Install" button. If you use multiple devices with that Gmail account, it will let you chose. Then, with your tablet connected to the Internet, the app will be automatically pushed to it and installed. If you're able to click this link directly on your tablet, it might work as well, I haven't tried that.

Comment: It says "installed" but I am wondering why I cannot type anything on the tablet!

Comment: I did not believe what it was saying. So, I still pushed "installed" button and it miraculously start to install it. I am just wondering why the heck it was saying "installed" :)

Comment: @Allan it'll say "installed" for any app that you've previously installed on the selected device, I think -- at least, that's been my experience. Happy it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in a different machine (desktop, laptop) and name it Gboard.
Transfer the folder to your device.
From your device, open the file browser, select that folder and hit Rename.
Hold your finger on the name and hit Copy.
Go to Play store. Hold your finger on the search bar and hit Paste.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from [apkmirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/gboard/) ?

For helping OP,  you can access this site on a desktop and download an apk. Specifically download the one that is compatible for your phone's architecture. Then once you have downloaded, transfer it to your phone (wire or bluetooth).

Remember to uncheck Unknown Sources in  Settings>Security (recheck it after installation) to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the prompt from someone above and adapted the approach by sending a friend a FB messenger message with one word Gboard.  I then copied and pasted the word into the Appstore on my phone.  The app was apparently installed but I was able to hit 'update' and hey presto I got my keyboard back - thank you to the person who made the first suggestion!!